# issue in send data to controller in popup form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-mvc

i use popup kendo grid and i use autocomplete for select Country and fill countryId to hidden input.

[image]

but when post data to controller , countryId is null.

[image]

please help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this issue by call event change() textbox in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at using the the select method built into kendo?
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#methods-select

Comment: No ,I using custom AutoComplete and using EditorTemplate.